# Nextcloud Calendar App "Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, nextcloud

I have a NC instance up and running and everything works good so far. No errors in nginx/error.log except that calendar is not working. I get a “Internal Server Error” everytime I click the Calendar icon. This is the nextcloud log:

> {"reqId":"5l4NLT39Z4PcucLEUkde","level":3,"time":"2021-12-22T21:20:07+01:00","remoteAddr":"91.53.xx.xx","user":"xxxx","app":"index","method":"GET","url":"/apps/calendar/","message":"Argument 1 passed to OC\Files\SimpleFS\SimpleFolder::__construct() must implement interface OCP\Files\Folder, instance of OC\Files\Node\File given, called in /var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/AppData/AppData.php on line 149","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0","version":"23.0.0.10","exception":{"Exception":"TypeError","Message":"Argument 1 passed to OC\Files\SimpleFS\SimpleFolder::__construct() must implement interface OCP\Files\Folder, instance of OC\Files\Node\File given, called in /var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/AppData/AppData.php on line 149","Code":0,"Trace":[{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/AppData/AppData.php","line":149,"function":"__construct","class":"OC\Files\SimpleFS\SimpleFolder","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Template/SCSSCacher.php","line":238,"function":"getFolder","class":"OC\Files\AppData\AppData","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Template/SCSSCacher.php","line":153,"function":"isCached","class":"OC\Template\SCSSCacher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Template/CSSResourceLocator.php","line":110,"function":"process","class":"OC\Template\SCSSCacher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Template/CSSResourceLocator.php","line":85,"function":"cacheAndAppendScssIfExist","class":"OC\Template\CSSResourceLocator","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Template/ResourceLocator.php","line":78,"function":"doFind","class":"OC\Template\CSSResourceLocator","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/TemplateLayout.php","line":353,"function":"find","class":"OC\Template\ResourceLocator","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/TemplateLayout.php","line":261,"function":"findStylesheetFiles","class":"OC\TemplateLayout","type":"::"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/legacy/OC_Template.php","line":182,"function":"__construct","class":"OC\TemplateLayout","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/public/AppFramework/Http/TemplateResponse.php","line":204,"function":"fetchPage","class":"OC_Template","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php","line":171,"function":"render","class":"OCP\AppFramework\Http\TemplateResponse","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/App.php","line":157,"function":"dispatch","class":"OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Route/Router.php","line":302,"function":"main","class":"OC\AppFramework\App","type":"::"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/base.php","line":1006,"function":"match","class":"OC\Route\Router","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/nextcloud/index.php","line":36,"function":"handleRequest","class":"OC","type":"::"}],"File":"/var/www/nextcloud/lib/private/Files/SimpleFS/SimpleFolder.php","Line":43,"CustomMessage":"--"},"id":"61c3889393b8c"}

Any ideas on that? Every other logs i looked up have no errors…

Kind regards!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think there was an update to the calender app about this issue.